# How to read a binary file starting from a specific part

Tags: java, android, string, file-io, binaryfiles

What I did in my code was to simply append a tag then some string data to a binary file using the append flag of `FileOutputStream`. Now, how do I read starting from the tag specified? I'm not sure where to start.

The file and string sizes are variable so I couldn't really trust it. The only thing constant is the tag.

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention that the file will be accessed from another thread/activity/app/device.

Code used for appending some data:

```
String TAG = "CLIPPYDATA-";
String content = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."; //size not fixed, sample purpose only.

FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/path/to/file", true);
try {
        output.write((TAG + content).getBytes());
} finally {
        //output.flush(); (should I?)
        output.close();
}
```

Sample output:

```
yyvAžîéÃI&8QÀ Ø +ZŠ( ¢Š( ¢Š(ÿÙCLIPPYDATA-The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

---

Sample input:

```
yyvAžîéÃI&8QÀ Ø +ZŠ( ¢Š( ¢Š(ÿÙCLIPPYDATA-The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

Desired Output:

```
CLIPPYDATA-The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

Comment: why don't you put the tag position at the end of the file?

Comment: if you put tag position at the end of the file, let's say, the last 8 bytes. then you can do as follows : read last 8 bytes -> get the position of the tag -> seek to position -> read the tag and content

Comment: @bladefury It's already at the end of the file. File content -> tag -> Content. I simply appended the new data. Anyways, I think you're saying that I should also place the position of where the appended data starts, right?

Comment: yes, append position info after you append tag and content

Comment: @bladefury Sounds legit. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98526/discussion-between-pandalion98-and-bladefury).

Comment: One question. **Why?** Why are you appending text to a binary file? Why are you implementing a file format you don't know how to read? What is the *actual* problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: @EJP First of all, it's an internal file type. It's the best alternative at the moment. There isn't any problem as far as I can see, aside from concatenating the needed data.

Comment: The problems are as follows: (a) you don't know to implement it; (b) you don't have a solution for multiple appends; and (c)  the format proposed basically doesn't make any actual sense in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in comment, here is a example:

for appending data:

```
    String TAG = "CLIPPYDATA-";
    String content = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."; //size not fixed, sample purpose only.
    File outputFile  = new File("/path/to/file");
    long fileLength = outputFile.length();
    FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outputFile, true);
    try {
        output.write((TAG + content).getBytes());
        byte[] bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(Long.SIZE / Byte.SIZE).putLong(fileLength).array();
        output.write(bytes);
    } finally {
        //output.flush(); (should I?)
        output.close();
    }
```

for reading data:

```
    RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile("/path/to/file", "rb");
    long endPositon = raf.length() - Long.SIZE / Byte.SIZE;
    // get last 8 bytes
    raf.seek(endPositon);
    long tagPosition = raf.readLong();
    raf.seek(tagPosition);
    byte[] bytes = new byte[endPositon - tagPosition];
    raf.read(bytes);
    String appendedData = new String(bytes);
    if (appendedData.startsWith(TAG)) {
        // appendedData is what you want
    }
```

Comment: @PandaLion98 Hard to see how this solves your problem unless there is only ever one append.

Answer (score 1):

Just `seek()` to where you wrote the tag.

**EDIT** 'Where you wrote the tag' is given by the file size before wrote it.

Comment: The problem is the offset is variable.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10634271)

Comment: @PandaLion98 That's ok, `seek()` takes an integer, which can be a variable.

Comment: @EJP Variable as in there's no fixed value :)

Comment: @PandaLion9 So your real problem is knowing the value, not doing the seek? That's not what it says in your question. The value you need is given by the file size before you do the append, of course.

Comment: @developer Of course it provides an answer to the question, what rubbish. The accepted answer says exactly the same thing.

Comment: @EJP I forgot to mention that the file will be accessed from another thread/activity/app/device.

Comment: Then you're going to have to create an index for this file giving all the tag offsets. Seems like you forgot all the relevant information.